# Accessing object of objects - JSON API

Tags: javascript

I'm wonder how to properly access to object of objects.I have JSON API, and I have to get some data from It.
FYI I'm using VueJS but I think that's not important thing here.

```
{
    "name": "Foo Bar",
    "details": {
        "color": "black",
        "slug": "foobar",
        "author": "John",
        "material": "Plastic"
    }
}
```

How could I access for e.g to the slug ? Those data are stored into parent object called product (VueJS Dev Tools)

Comment: `product.details.slug`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/878wjjnt/

Answer (score 0):

```
var slug = product.details.slug
```

Comment: I tried this way for sure but I get error Cannot read property ... of undefined

Comment: Well, then product is probably not defined or not accessible, try console.log(product).

Comment: Seems like this could be Vue Related stuff, I'm not sure could I post here the vue code ?

Comment: Your question did originally not seem to be Vue specific so the question was obviously closed. Personally I don't know anything about Vue, see if you can find any answer for this at google, else try to dig a little deeper to identify the problem and then make a new question.